# Google Play Developer Console : How to Get Notification Emails (with restricted app access)?

Tags: android, notifications, console, playback

I am a team member and don't have full permissions / full access of an app at work. I recently discovered that the app was removed from Google Play due to not complying with a policy change announced 2 months ago. The person with full access does not regularly check his emails.

Is there any way that with my restricted access, I can get emails pertaining to Google Play developer rule changes, app removals, and app submission progress? I've looked in the Play Console and don't see anything I can set. I didn't even get an email when confirming the invite for my restricted access to the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't as you're are member only. Ask owner to give access you as Admin

Comment: @MD Even Admins don't necessarily get these notifications, having experienced this recently. A colleague told me that the play console android app will notify you on a device but I personally haven't seen it yet.